# Magento 2 CSV Import: Not possible to import disabled products?

Tags: product, magento2, import, importexport, magento-2.0.1

In the Magento 2 import/export, the "status" column is missing.

How can I import products with status "disabled"?

Adding the columns manually in a CSV for import, does not help, it's ignored.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a good question for https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it: The column is actually still there, but is titled `product_online` (the attribute `status` has not changed though)

Comment: Thanks for that, I was also looking for the correct name to use. Value should be `1` for "enabled". If you check the folder `dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/_files/` you see a lot of examples that are used for the tests